# Invalid class file error when trying to package Blackberry app

Tags: java, blackberry

I am facing a problem with blackberry packaging, here is the error info

> C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Temp\rapc_0c000678.dir\com\test\bbapp\Api$1.class: Error!: Invalid class file: Incorrect classfile version    bb      line 0  BlackBerry Packaging Problem

I am new to blackberry programming, but I am familiar with android and windows phone. I tried running a sample blackberry app, it can be packaged successfully.

I am using eclipse and blackberry plug-in.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set proper compliance level?

```
Invalid class file: Incorrect classfile version
```

Relates to your compiler version is not supported. [See this link from BB Support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Incorrect-class-file-error-in-BB-IDE-while-build/td-p/441501) may help you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click project in Eclipse
2. Choose properties
3. Select Java compiler
4. Check "Enable project specific settings"
5. Change java version on dropdown (try them all if you need)
6. Click "Apply" button
7. Click "Ok" button

If it doesn't work in first trial, just repeat steps with different version in step 5

Answer (score 1):

You should review your project settings in Eclipse. Verify that you're using the correct Blackberry JDE version in the Build Path